# Datatable search by LINQ to avoid duplication

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a column in dataTable with blank rows

```
Column1
A
B
C

D

E
```

I need to set if exist and to avoid adding, but blank rows should not be counted. Only rows with data should be in the (if exists). Thanks

```
 bool exists = dt.Select().ToList().Exists(row => row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox)



if(exists == true)
{}
else
```

// it includes blank so it goes to true, which I need is blank rows should not be included.

Comment: How can a blank row be included if you search for "search field"? Just handle the case that the user didn't enter anything into the search TextBox.

Comment: that search field is a textbox that can be empty or whitespaces. So first I need to collect all the rows withour blank then in that collection I will check if exist based on the search fields. But I don't know the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoiding duplicate code in Linq Select method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649878/avoiding-duplicate-code-in-linq-select-method)

Comment: Can you provide a meaningful example? _"search field can be empty or whitespaces"_ .. _"...collect all the rows without blanks"_ .. _"I will check if exist based on the search field"_ Doesn't make sense.

Comment: bool exists = dt.Select().ToList().Exists(row => row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox), I already had this code but it includes blank string "". I need to bypass that "" blank string.

Comment: @Alphatrix: edit your question and provide a meaningful sample with input, data and expected result.

Comment: I don't understand why can't you add the condition in the `Exists` lambda? Also, why does it return false? why would the extra rows bother if you use `Exists`? it should return true.

Comment: I need to return false to output Messagebox.

Comment: So, if the only thing missing is check for empty string of the txtbox, then add it, instead of trying to reduce rows. Which you can do either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lignesNonContainEmptyString = dt.Select()
                   .Where(row => row["column1"] != null 
                                && row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox 
                                && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["column1"].ToString()))

bool exists = lignes.Count() != 0;
```

OR

```
bool exists = dt.Select()
                       .Any(row => row["column1"] != null 
                                    && row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox 
                                    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["column1"].ToString()))
```

Comment: bool exists = dt.Select().ToList().Exists(row => row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox), this code already work but it does not support blank rows, I need to bypass those blank rows, and it should return true or false

Comment: Wow, thanks it really worked and saved a lot of time.

Comment: Instead of `lignes.Count() != 0`, I like `Lines.Any()`. Readable and more efficient.

Comment: `dt.Select().ToList()` please not! `DataTable` is an in-memory collection that can be queried with LINQ(`AsEnumerable()`). `DataTable.Select` will iterate all rows and  create a new `DataRow[]`. `ToList()` will iterate all rows and create a `List(Of DataRow)`. Instead of `Exists` you can use `Any`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I see a bug in the matrix. Same comment same author :)

Answer (score 1):

You would like to return `false` if the textbox is empty, so add the condition for the textbox.

```
bool exists = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtbox)
              && dt.Select().ToList()
                   .Exists(row => row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox)
```

By the way, instead of using `.Select().ToList()`, you can add a reference to `System.Data.DataTableExtensions` and use the Extension `AsEnumerable`:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Any( .....
```

Answer (score 0):

this code can help you

```
from a in list where ( Column1 != null || Column1 != "")
&& Column1 == searchfield
select a
```

Comment: bool exists = dt.Select().ToList().Exists(row => row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox). I need to modify this code, becuase it includes the blank input

Answer (score 0):

How about this: non linq way

```
bool DataTableNonEmptyCount()
{
int count =0;
foreach (DataColumn col in row.Table.Columns)
    if (!row.IsNull(col))
      count ++;

  return count;
}
```

This will return a count of all non null row in column.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Thierry's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52290576/6560478), you can also use the [Any(predicate) syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var existsLineWithoutEmptyString = 
             dt.AsEnumerable()
               .Any(row => row["column1"] != null 
                           && row["column1"].ToString() == txtbox 
                           && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["column1"].ToString()))
```